# accessing xaml control from mainviewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have maps control in my xaml windows phone apps and I want to access my map from my mainviewmodel since there is where I put all my logic code in there, is there anyway to add it?

> Geoposition position =
>                   await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
>                   TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
>                   TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

```
            var gpsCenter =
                new GeoCoordinate(
                    position.Coordinate.Latitude,
                    position.Coordinate.Longitude);
            myMap.SetView(gpsCenter, 10);
            latitude = position.Coordinate.Latitude;
            longitude = position.Coordinate.Longitude;
            UpdateTransport();
```

this is the code that supposed to be in there if i just put all my code into mainpage.xaml.cs

> myMap.SetView(gpsCenter, 10);

this is the code that i trying to add into my xaml component, it only doing some zoom and moving my map to exactly the phone position data, i can put it into mainpage.xaml.cs but since there is 2 variable that i needed in my mainviewmodel (latitude and longitude) so i decided to put it all into mainviewmodel

edit

```
    private GeoCoordinate _center;
    public GeoCoordinate center
    {
        get { return _center; }
        set { this.SetProperty(ref this._center, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        center = new GeoCoordinate();
    }

    private async void LoadTransportData()
    {
        Geolocator geolocator = new Geolocator();
        geolocator.DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 50;
    Geoposition position =
                    await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync(
                    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

   center = new GeoCoordinate(
                            position.Coordinate.Latitude,
                            position.Coordinate.Longitude);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that. Your view model should *never* interact with the view directly. You should create a bindable `GeoCoordinate` property in your view model and bind that to the `Map.Center` property.

This way you still have clean separation of UI and view model code.

--
EDIT: Add the following property to your view model

```
GeoCoordinate _center;
public GeoCoordinate Center
{
    get { return _center; }
    set
    {
        _center = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Center"); // or whatever here
    }
}
```

Bind `Map.Center` to that property in XAML.

Comment: how to create bindable geocoordinate?

Comment: already did what you do but get System.ArgumentNullException any idea why?

Comment: Because by default, `Center` is `null`. Initialize it to `new GeoCoordinate` in the constructor. I mean, the error said _argument is null_.

Comment: hmm?i'm sorry i don't get it... can you give me some code example?

Comment: `Center = new GeoCoordinate`.

Comment: i already add center into my mainviewmodel constructor but my maps just not getting centered i have put my whole code into edit